# New instal on New box keeps on crashing

Tags: boot

Built a new PC and installed 20.04 on it as I was very satisfied with running 18.xx on my old PC. Ran for a week with intermittent crashing on startup or during browsing. Now it just doesn't boot at all and gives me this error

I odes that where part of a corrupted orphan linked list found.
/dev/nvmeon1p2 found run fsck manualy
Exited with code 4 the root on dev/nvmeon1p2 requires manual fsck.

But typing fsck on that gives an error 2 no such file.

Sda1 no result.
Sda2 comes back clean.
3 4 and 5 no result.

What can I do? Tried to re install from the USB but it won't give me the option.

I.m Not a noob but I am close to being one.

Comment: Details are unclear. Edit your question and provide the exact commands you are using as well as the entire error message. Please use [formatting](https://askubuntu.com/editing-help#code) so we can tell it apart from the surrounding text.

Comment: With the available level of detail I'd say: The nvme-disk (or related electronics on the motherboard) is broken. I hold ESD-damage as the most likely cause; unless you know that you e.g. did use simple but proper means to avoid that ==hint==> https://www.google.com/search?q=ESD+wrist+band

Comment: Thanks for the fast response. I can't seem to ad a picture of the screen.  So typed out manually. Thats why I may be fuzzy

Comment: Have built PC's before. Used a piece of copper wire from my wrist to the central heater in the living room. Not exactly lab grade but hopefully effective.

Comment: Yes, that's correct that you cannot upload images as a new contributor. But at the very least you can take a picture of your screen and use it as a reference so that you can accurately type the information in your question. Pictures of text are discouraged anyway. Please take the time to make sure the information you provide is complete and accurate and proofread what you write so the information is clearly communicated. Any help we can provide is limited by how well you've communicated the problem. Help us help you.